# When running the command npm init vue@latest, error is shown and command breaks

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to create a vue.js project using the command npm init vue@latest, but it throws an error.
I am new to vue.js, kindly spare some of your time for this.

Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMfTc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// I solved this problem, I was using node version 8.15.1, I updated it to node version 16.15.1, and afterwards, the command npm init vue@latest worked fine.